# ¿Como obtener NULL's en está consulta de join's en MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server

Buen dia compañeros, tengo una duda, estoy haciendo una consulta multitablas (inner join, left join, y un cross join) 
tengo la siguientes tablas principales

`DETALLEPLANTILLA`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`DETALLEEVALUACION`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`EVALUACION`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito que el resultado sea de la siguiente forma

```
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
| IdDetallePlantilla | IdOperacion   | Orden | IdEvaluacion | Valor |
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
| 1                  | 1             |   1   |     27151    | NULL  |
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
| 2                  | 1             |   2   |     27151    | NULL  |
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
|                              .......                              | 
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
| 21                 | 1             |   1   |     27151    |   1   |
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
| 22                 | 1             |   2   |     27151    |   1   |
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
| 23                 | 1             |   3   |     27151    |   2   |
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
|                               .......                             | 
|--------------------|---------------|-------|--------------|-------|
```

Este es el codigo que utilizo está un poco resumido pero considero que es lo escencial

**He corregido las tablas necesarias pues por Id Evaluacion necesito me genere una plantilla ya sea con valores null o los valores del detalleplantilla**

```
select detpl.IdDetalle,detpl.IdOperacion,detpl.Orden,detev.IdEvaluacion,detev.Valor 
from QM_DETPLANTILLA detpl
LEFT join QM_DETEVALUACION detev on detpl.IdDetalle=detev.IdDetPlantilla
left join QM_EVALUACION ev on detev.IdEvaluacion=ev.IdEvaluacion
where  detpl.IdOperacion=@idoperacion
and ev.UsuarioCrea=@evaluador
and ev.FechaCrea between @fecha and DATEADD(day,1,@fecha)`
```

Comment: estás seguro que estás haciendo un `LEFT JOIN`?, puedes postear el código que estás usando?

Comment: Como comenta @Lamak, eso deberia de funcionar con un left join, solo que en el from debe ir la tabla DETALLEPLANTILLA y en el join DETALLEEVALUACION

Comment: Agrega que resultado trae tu query

Comment: acabo de actualizar mi pregunta esta mas entendible creo, me faltó agregar el idevaluacion

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es obtener todos los valores usa un **Full Outer Join** para obtener nulos de ambos lados del join

Comment: cuando uso el full join me da el mismo conjunto de resultados que con un left o un inner, no me da el resultado añadiendo los null

Answer (score 0):

Solucione mi problema, el modelo estaba mal diseñado, agrege el IdOperacion en la tabla Evaluacion, como necesitaba que me genere una plantilla completa por evaluacion y en ella poner los detalles

`select detpl.IdDetalle,detpl.IdOperacion,detpl.Orden,ev.IdEvaluacion,detev.Valor 
from QM_DETPLANTILLA detpl
inner join QM_EVALUACION ev on detpl.IdOperacion=ev.IdOperacion
left join QM_DETEVALUACION detev on detpl.IdDetalle=detev.IdDetPlantilla and ev.IdEvaluacion=detev.IdEvaluacion
where  detpl.IdOperacion=@idoperacion
and ev.UsuarioCrea=@evaluador
and ev.FechaCrea between @fecha and DATEADD(day,1,@fecha)
order by IdEvaluacion,IdDetalle,Orden`